# get all colors in a pixelated image

Tags: android, image, bitmap

i am using android studio and i want to get all colors in a pixelated image. I have a pixelated image of 50x50 size. here is that image

[image]

I'm reading all pixels in it by using that code.

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.abc);
for(int x=0; x<50; x++){
    for(int y=0; y<50; y++){    
        pixelColor = bmp.getPixel(x,y);
        if(pixelColor == Color.BLACK) {
            //The pixel is black
        }else if(pixelColor == Color.WHITE) {
            //The pixel was white
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem is that, image has also black color in it and in my code black color condition never get true. There could be colors other than just red,green,or blue. it'll be great if i can get ids of all colors because i want to extract all colors in that image. please let me know where i'm doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: have you successfully draw a image pixel on screen?

Comment: I'm not drawing anything, i just need colors in pixelated image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find its `rgb` values

```
int redValue = Color.red(pixelColor);
int blueValue = Color.blue(pixelColor);
int greenValue = Color.green(pixelColor);
```

then you can find your color.

**UPDATE 1**

```
color = Color.rgb(redValue, greenValue,blueValue);
if(color == Color.BLACK)
    //The pixel is black
}else if(color == Color.WHITE) {
    //The pixel was white
}
```

Comment: The color may not be pure black or white in your pixel.

Comment: its getting too many colors instead of apparent visible colors in the image. may be a slight color difference is being considered new color. how can we pick apparent visible colors?

Answer (score 0):

The concept of black might be something like 'a very dark grey' but for a computer black is the absent of light, thus any color.

Simply but, the black you perceive in the image most likely is some form of dark grey as pixels in images tend to be kind of mixed together with their neighbors to create a smoother image.
As Color.BLACK equals to 0x000000 in hex (0 red, 0 green, 0 blue) it won't match on anything except exactly black. You'll have to match on darker tones of grey as well; to do so, have a look at a color palette and decide which grey you deem as dark enough. Grey is always a mix of green, red and blue in roughly the same aspect (eg 5 red, 6 blue, 4 green). Then simply check whether the red/green/blue parts are below the thresholds you deemed as dark enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a set of all colors in the bitmap and use this list later on, eg:

```
Set<Integer> allColors = new TreeSet<Integer>();
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.abc);
for(int x=0; x<50; x++){
    for(int y=0; y<50; y++){    
        pixelColor = bmp.getPixel(x,y);
        allColors.add(pixelColor);
    }
}
```